# how to do something when a particular card is fully loaded in Recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

How to do something(like call an intent or start a new activity) when a Card is fully loaded in a Recycler view? Note, **I have only one Card visible at a time in my Recycler View.**
I want to start a new activity as soon as a particular type of card finish loading in the recycler view. 
Right now, I am having onClickListener to start the new activity. 
Is it possible to achieve this, if yes how? 
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how are you loading the card? Using a loader you could start the activity onLoadFinished

see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html

Comment: Thank you but I am not using LoaderManager in my app.

Answer (score 0):

implement you intent in

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {  

}
```

in recycler view by checking the position of item . As here all items are added in recycler view .

Comment: That's what I was trying to do but it's not straightforward! The new activity should start as soon as card is loaded, so while its loading it has to show a placeholder or something so in "onBindViewHolder" I have that view that needs to be shown while scrolling and loading the card(since the cards are basically full-screen).